# Why is my mono/XSP site loading slow?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, mono

I have two sites on the same server. One is loading perfectly and incredibly fast. The other is an equally complex site except a bit less javascript and 0 images. Its taking several seconds to load and there is a 1 in 3 chance that i get a Http500 error. WTF

I grabbed the lastest 2.6.? version of mono, mod_mono and xsp (libgdiplus-2.6.7, xsp-2.6.5, mod_mono-2.6.3 and mono 2.6.7)

This is whats in apache error.log

```
[Mon Jan 03 19:33:40 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Mon Jan 03 19:33:40 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
[Mon Jan 03 19:34:52 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Mon Jan 03 19:34:52 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Mon Jan 03 19:34:52 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
[Mon Jan 03 19:34:52 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
```

this is the page error

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.
>   Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
>   PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch
>   mod_mono/2.6.3 Server

Comment: Can you post your apache configuration?

Comment: @Tomi: Which one? The site config? something else? The two sites are configured exactly the same way. Just different document paths.

Comment: Yes, apache config for the website (virtual host). I remember having the "End of file found:" error, so I can check if the issue isn't in configuration.

Comment: alright @Tomi The site that works perfectly is http://www.pastie.org/pastes/1426871/text the site with random errors http://www.pastie.org/pastes/1426879/text (delete `/text` to remove raw text mode)

Comment: I'm using apache configuration from http://tomi.developmententity.sk/Blog/Post/5 stated under "Apache and mod_mono configuration" for asp.net mvc based websites. Your website is based on asp.net webforms?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem?